# Tabindex on inserted fields

Tags: javascript, forms

Given that

1. The Browser has a page loaded with an exisitng field (call it `ef`) with `tabindex=1`,
2. Two new fields are inserted via bookmarklet (`nf1` and `nf2`)

`first time` (incorrect behavior)
When the mouse is clicked on nf1 followed by a tab
the focus acts as if the tab was entered from field ef and goes to a place
other than `nf2`.

`second time` (correct behavior)
Now, if the same actions were repeated i.e. mouse clicked on `nf1` followed
by a tab the focus goes to `nf2`.

One way I've ensured that the focus goes to `nf2` from `nf1` the `first time` around is
to hardcode tabindex values to fields `nf1` and `nf2`. But this is suboptimal as one
needs to make sure that there are no `tabindex` conflicts i.e. if there are two fields
where `tabindex=1` than focus goes from one to the other instead of to the 
proximate `tabindex=2`

So, what can be done to ensure that the behaviour that manifests
on the `second time` manifests on the first time.

ps: jquery is available on the page

Answer (score 0):

I rarely use the `tabindex` attribute so I haven't encountered this property.  However, I have written interfaces with similar functionality (fields are added dynamically) with normal tab behavior.  I would suggest just removing the `tabindex` attribute and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: well, ef is on the original page authored by someone else, removing tabindex on bookmarklet insert does not alter the behavior.